# How to create relations via repository mixins in loopback 4

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

I have a requirement where models and repositories can be extended via mixins with the purpose to add fields and relations.

Regarding adding fields to models is already achieved (even with some drawbacks like not keeping hidden fields),
but i'm not able to also create a repository mixin which defines a relation on the model-mixed-in field.

Basically i can't find a way to get the repositoryGetter object to configure the relation in the mixin constructor, as per [docs defined here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/BelongsTo-relation.html#configuring-a-belongsto-relation), since decorators can't be used in the mixin constructor.

The incriminated code is the following one.

```js
    // mixin stuff above

    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    (superClass: R, options?: GenericObject) => {

        class Extended extends superClass {

            // create the main relation accessor object
            private user: BelongsToAccessor<OnitUser, ID>;
 
            @repository.getter('OnitUserRepository') public onitUserRepositoryGetter: Getter<OnitUserRepository>;

            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
            constructor(...params: any[]) {
                super(...params);

                // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
                // @ts-ignore This mixin applies to a DefaultCrudRepository. We know we have this function.
                this.log = this.createBelongsToAccessorFor('user', this.onitUserRepositoryGetter);
                        
                // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
                // @ts-ignore This mixin applies to a DefaultCrudRepository. We know we have this function.
                this.registerInclusionResolver('user', this.user.inclusionResolver);
            }
         
       }
       return Extended
    }
```

The alternative way to get the repositoryGetter i need is decorating a single property, but it appear to be injected later in the instansiation flow so it is not available in the constructor.

Suggestion on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way. In the constructor, all the code is replaced with:

```js
      const proxiedInclusionResolver: InclusionResolver<T, User> =
        ( sourceEntities: T[], inclusion: InclusionFilter, _options?: Options) => {
           if (!this.user){
              // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
              // @ts-ignore This mixin applies to a DefaultCrudRepository. We know we have this function.
              this.user = this.createBelongsToAccessorFor('user', this.userRepositoryGetter);
           }
           return this.user.inclusionResolver(sourceEntities, inclusion, _options);
      };

      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
      // @ts-ignore This mixin applies to a DefaultCrudRepository. We know we have this function.
      this.registerInclusionResolver('user', proxiedInclusionResolver);
```

This generate the accessot on the fly the first time the relation is accessed, and in that moment the repositoryGetter is already valorized.